# Configure windows service hosted WCF REST to work on HTTPS?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

i have built a WCF REST that is hosted on a windows service. it works with regular HTTP calls. what are the steps to make it work with SSL (HTTPS?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the X.509 cert and configure it to your WCF service endpoint using httpcfg.exe or netsh. See [here](http://www.leastprivilege.com/WalkthroughSettingUpASelfHostedWCFServiceWithSSL.aspx).